# Warnings while using apt-get update on Raspbian

Tags: apt, software-sources

I've been trying to install Plex on my pi and failing(Novice at anything computers). I've tried a few times, and I think I may have finally got it. Now when I go to update, and get these warnings:

```
root@raspberry:~# apt-get update

Hit:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease

Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease

Ign:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease

Hit:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease

Hit:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch Release

Hit:6 https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease

Reading package lists... Done

W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'amd64'

W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1

W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:10 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list:1
```

---

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list


deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free  
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free  
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free 



"# Uncomment lines below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'"

"#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free"

"#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free"

"#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free"

"deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main"
```

---

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list


deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main
```

---

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get update

Get:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]

Ign:2 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease

Hit:3 https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease

Get:4 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]

Hit:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch Release

Get:7 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [25.4 kB]
```

Fetched 211 kB in 7s (27.5 kB/s)

```
Reading package lists... Done

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'amd64'

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dev2day.de/pms stretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Comment: Yes. I am using Raspbian on an older dell laptop.

Comment: Sorry totally ignorant to the computer world lol

Comment: @Kulfy or he could try my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got duplicate entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` line # 10, and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list` line #1.

Edit your question and show us line #10 (`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`), and the entire pms.list file (`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list`), and I'll take a look for you.

**Update #1:**

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`...

And change:

```
"deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main"
```

to:

```
"#deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main"
```

**Update #2:**

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pms.list`...

And change:

```
deb https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main
```

To:

```
deb [arch=armhf] https://dev2day.de/pms/ stretch main
```

**Update #3:**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Comment: So there was an error when I tried to use "gedit" command. I went ahead and tried it a different way. Added results to post as an edit

Comment: my apologies I had to step away to go to work. I add the # in front of the source list text, that seems to have fixed the duplicate entries. I went ahead and updated the post. After having done the "#" fix I'm still getting this "Skipping acquire of configured file" message any idea what that means/ how to fix it? your help has been great so far!

Comment: @LeviWentz did you do Update #2? I'll add an Update #3. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: update 2 worked perfectly, selected the check mark, is that all I need to do to accept your answer? Much appreciate the help!